# Is it possible to curry the other way around in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

Let's assume this function:

```
def autoClosing(f: {def close();})(t: =>Unit) = {
    t
    f.close()
}
```

and this snippet:

```
val a = autoClosing(new X)(_)
a {
 println("before close")
}
```

is it possible to curry the first part? Something like:

```
val a = autoClosing(_) { println("before close") }
```

so that I could send the objects on which close should be performed, and have the same block executed on them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the snippet you have given works, as long as you give the type of the placeholder character.

Therefore, the code you are looking for is:

```
val a = autoClosing(_: {def close();}) { println("before close") }
```

which compiles and works as expected :).

A couple of notes:

- You can make your life easier if you define a type alias for an `AnyRef` type having a `close` method, something like `type Closeable = AnyRef {def close()}`, or an appropriate interface.
- The code snippet `autoClosing(_: Closeable){ ... }` is actually equivalent to the following expanded anonymous function: `c: Closeable => autoClosing(c){ ... }`. The wildcard character is just shorthand for a partially applied function. You need to give the type of the `_` as the type inferer unfortunately cannot infer the type in this case.

Hope it helps,

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Comment: You're welcome. Added a couple of notes to expand my answer :). Unfortunately, the type inferer cannot infer the type of the wildcard here.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can flip the parameters:

```
def flip[A1, A2, B](f: A1 => A2 => B): A2 => A1 => B = x1 => x2 => f(x2)(x1)
```

In your case:

```
val a = flip(autoClosing){ println("before close") }
```

Edit:
I've added some braces to help the human parser:

```
def flip[A1, A2, B](f: (A1 => (A2 => B))): (A2 => (A1 => B)) = {
    x1 => (x2 => f(x2)(x1))
}
```

Flip converts a function `(A1 => (A2 => B))` to `(A2 => (A1 => B))`.

```
scala> def x(x1 : Int)(x2 : Long) = 1.0 * x1 / x2
x: (Int)(Long)Double

scala> val f = flip(x)
f: (Long) => (Int) => Double = <function>

scala> val g = f(1)
g: (Int) => Double = <function>

scala> val h = g(2)
h: Double = 2.0

scala> x(1)(2)
res0: Double = 0.5
```

Comment: Can you explain that monster a bit? :)

Comment: I added some braces and sample code so see the partial application in action. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm happy to see so many people answering Scala questions nowadays. It does make it harder for me to come up with something, however. Here's an alternative to [Flaviu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149284/flaviu-cipcigan)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920998/is-it-possible-to-curry-the-other-way-around-in-scala/1921098#1921098).

```
val a: {def close();} => Unit = autoClosing(_) { println("before close") }
```

Of course, the proper solution is to define autoClosing in a way compatible with how you are going to use it.

Comment: I'm happy about that too :). I'm giving up Ruby for Scala ... it's got everything I wanted in a language.